# SDL chinese input error, output is completely different from input

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-ttf

I'm not a native English speaker, so my English may not be so accurate. If you have any question, just ask me.
Here's the question. I want to input Chinese characters in my program, so I follow the SDL tutorial (https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials/TextInput?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=redraw&titlesearch=Titles). To test my program, I output the characters which I input. However, they're completely different from the input.
Here's the code

```
char text[100];   int done=0;
while (!done) {
    SDL_Event event;
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
            done = SDL_TRUE;
            break;
        case SDL_TEXTINPUT:
            strcat(text, event.text.text);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Basically the same as the tutorial, however, when I input "你好", the output is like this:
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvPJL.png)

Can anybody help me?
Regards.

Comment: How do you input ni-hao?  Do you use the Chinese/Japanese IME or do you switch to a chinese keyboard and type it in?

Comment: @cup: I use a Chinese IME.

Comment: Which routine are you using for showing the output?  Is it TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid

Answer (score 1):

[strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/) wants a NUL terminated string as destination:

> *destination:*
>       Pointer to the destination array, which **should contain a C string**, and be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.

Switch to:

```
char text[100] = "";
```

Comment: actually, I used memset(text, 0, sizeof(char)*100) in my code, but I forgot to add it in the question. and I tried your solution, it didn't work either.